# Receiving iOS Push Notifications on Delphi 10 Seattle

Tags: ios, delphi, push-notification, provisioning-profile, delphi-10-seattle

The main goal here is to generate and *receive* `Push Notifications` for `iOS` using Delphi 10 Seattle.

I'm trying to follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_C5_GxQhk4) but so far I've been able only to successfully *send* push notifications.

There's [this incredible tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) that helped me to understand better about App ID's, Provisioning Profiles, Certificates, PEM files, SSL connections and so on. This is basically how I see it now (*yes, thats a real board*):

[image]

But the funny thing is about the Provisioning Profile that I need to link at Delphi. **It must be the same reverse domain name as the APNS certificate.**

I'm able to visualize the `Provisioning Profile` with `Push Support` I created at Apple's Member Center at Delphi's `Tools > Options > Provisioning`.

[image]

But I'm not able to see any Provisioning Profiles that doesn't belong to a **iOS Team Provisioning Profile** at `Project > Options > Provisioning`, even though the provided `CFBundleIdentifier` at `Version Info` matches the same Bundle Identifier (App ID) from Xcode.

[image]

I can only run the application if I include the `Team Prefix` on the `Bundle ID`, but I feel like I must be doing something wrong.

The notifications will only work if the application has the correct certificates linked to it.

And this is how I'm getting the application token:

```
procedure TFormPush.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var

    FormPush          : TFormPush;
    APushService      : TPushService;
    AServiceConnection: TPushServiceConnection;

    ADeviceID   : string;
    AdeviceToken: string;

begin

    APushService := TPushServiceManager.Instance.GetServiceByName(TPushService.TServiceNames.APS);

    AServiceConnection        := TPushServiceConnection.Create(APushService);
    AServiceConnection.Active := True;

    ADeviceID    := APushService.DeviceIDValue[TPushService.TDeviceIDNames.DeviceID];
    AdeviceToken := APushService.DeviceTokenValue[TPushService.TDeviceTokenNames.DeviceToken];

    ShowMessage(AdeviceToken);

end;
```

It took me a lot of effort to get here, but I'm still failing to receive the push notifications.

What are the possible mistakes I must be doing?

Comment: In my experience this can happen if your provisioning profile has expired or if you have multiple provisioning profiles (some of which have expired) in the keychain.